# ffmpeg conversions lead to incorrect time on vlc

Tags: ffmpeg

I am converting a video using the following:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -analyzeduration 2147483647 -probesize 2147483647 -i /home/michael/Desktop/transcodingtemp/output.mkv -max_interleave_delta 0 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:s:0]overlay[v1];[v1]scale=w=-2:h=720:flags=gauss[v2]" -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -map "[v2]" -map 0:1? -map 0:2? -map 0:3? -map 0:4? -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -codec:v:0 libx264 -crf 23 -c:a aac -b:a 320k -sn /home/michael/Desktop/transcodingtemp/output.mkv_transcoded.mkv
ffmpeg version 4.2.2-1ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-3ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/home/michael/Desktop/transcodingtemp/output.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:05:00.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3243 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 159.493000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 159.493000, end 300.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 02
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 1368113
      DURATION-eng    : 01:38:24.941000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 141577
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1009828723
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v34.0.0 ('Sight and Seen') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-06-07 05:38:49
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      ENCODER         : Lavc57.107.100 h264_vaapi
      DURATION        : 00:05:00.112000000
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 310439
      DURATION-eng    : 01:38:24.938000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 276794
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 229141045
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v34.0.0 ('Sight and Seen') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-06-07 05:38:49
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      ENCODER         : Lavc57.107.100 aac
      DURATION        : 00:05:00.010000000
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle, 1920x1080 (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : English Sub (Translated from Japanese)
      BPS-eng         : 17619
      DURATION-eng    : 01:35:43.029000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 2298
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 12648785
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v34.0.0 ('Sight and Seen') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-06-07 05:38:49
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 00:04:54.440000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #0:2 (pgssub) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  scale (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[matroska,webm @ 0x5571480cfb80] sub2video: using 1920x1080 canvas
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=23 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to '/home/michael/Desktop/transcodingtemp/output.mkv_transcoded.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 159.493000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 01
    Chapter #0:1: start 159.493000, end 300.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 02
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: aac (LC) ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 320 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 310439
      DURATION-eng    : 01:38:24.938000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 276794
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 229141045
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v34.0.0 ('Sight and Seen') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2019-06-07 05:38:49
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      DURATION        : 00:05:00.010000000
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
[matroska @ 0x5571480fc080] Starting new cluster due to timestampte=1026.8kbits/s speed=2.92x    
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame= 7075 fps= 69 q=-1.0 Lsize=   38040kB time=00:05:00.01 bitrate=1038.7kbits/s speed=2.91x    
video:26400kB audio:11493kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.388885%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] frame I:57    Avg QP:14.50  size: 67869
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] frame P:1978  Avg QP:18.64  size:  8377
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] frame B:5040  Avg QP:24.34  size:  1308
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] consecutive B-frames:  3.2%  3.8%  5.1% 87.9%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] mb I  I16..4: 32.8% 45.8% 21.5%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] mb P  I16..4:  2.5%  5.9%  0.9%  P16..4: 16.6%  7.0%  4.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:62.7%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.3%  0.1%  B16..8: 14.6%  1.0%  0.1%  direct: 0.7%  skip:83.0%  L0:42.8% L1:52.9% BI: 4.4%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] 8x8 transform intra:58.7% inter:71.8%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 36.5% 56.5% 28.2% inter: 3.8% 5.5% 0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 46% 30%  5% 20%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 19% 25%  4%  6%  5%  6%  4%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 23% 16%  5%  7%  7%  7%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 52% 23% 19%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:9.3% UV:5.3%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] ref P L0: 71.0% 14.0% 11.2%  3.7%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] ref B L0: 91.6%  6.8%  1.6%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] ref B L1: 96.6%  3.4%
[libx264 @ 0x5571480fdf40] kb/s:0.03
[aac @ 0x55714810e580] Qavg: 3812.204
```

The problem is that when I check the video, I get on VLC an incorrect max time 1197 hours. I know the problem is caused by the overlay (filter_complex) but don't know why. I also tried just "-filter_complex "[0:v][0:s:0]overlay[v1]" but even produces the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 Things:
1. why do you only convert the `0` stream? you could just do `-c:v libx264` (instead of `-codec:v:0 libx264`)
2. you could try to use the `shortest` statement in your `overlay`-statement. Like this `[0:v][0:s:0]overlay=shortest[v1]`,

See here for more:
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#framesync

You could also try reencoding your transcoded video without filters and see if you get errors or if the time is fixed after that.

Greetings

(This is posted as an answer and not a comment, because I can't comment)

Comment: Shortest solved it. I set it to shortest=1. But I am not sure why shortest fixes it.

Comment: Probably one your videos is extremely long, or the overlay filter has issues with overlaying the subtitle stream and keeping the timestamps intact. Eitherway usually in an overlay you don't want to run one stream, while the other already ended. The shortest flag just tells the filter to stop when the first stream ends and discard the remainder of the other streams.